# Inconsistent internal representation of dates in matplotlib/pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, python-datetime

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.to_datetime(['2016-05-01', '2016-11-01', '2017-05-02'])
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3],
                     'b': [4, 5, 6]}, index=index)
ax = data.plot()
print(ax.get_xlim())

# Out: (736066.7, 736469.3)
```

Now, if we change the last date.

```
index = pd.to_datetime(['2016-05-01', '2016-11-01', '2017-05-01'])
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3],
                     'b': [4, 5, 6]}, index=index)
ax = data.plot()
print(ax.get_xlim())

# Out: (184.8, 189.2)
```

The first example seems consistent with the [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html):

> Matplotlib represents dates using floating point numbers specifying the number of days since 0001-01-01 UTC, plus 1

Why does the second example return something seemingly completely different? I'm using pandas version 0.22.0 and matplotlib version 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas uses different units to represents dates and times on the axes, depending on the range of dates/times in use. This means that different locators are in use.

In the first case,

```
print(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator())
# Out: pandas.plotting._converter.PandasAutoDateLocator
```

in the second case

```
print(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator())
# pandas.plotting._converter.TimeSeries_DateLocator
```

You may force pandas to always use the `PandasAutoDateLocator` using the `x_compat` argument,

```
df.plot(x_compat=True)
```

This would ensure to always get the same datetime definition, consistent with the `matplotlib.dates` convention.

The drawback is that this removes the nice quarterly ticking

[image]

and replaces it with the standard ticking

[image]

On the other hand it would then allow to use the very customizable `matplotlib.dates` tickers and formatters. For example to get quarterly ticks/labels

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import pandas as pd

index = pd.to_datetime(['2016-05-01', '2016-11-01', '2017-05-01'])
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3],
                     'b': [4, 5, 6]}, index=index)
ax = data.plot(x_compat=True)

# Quarterly ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator((1,4,7,10)))

# Formatting:
def func(x,pos):
    q = (mdates.num2date(x).month-1)//3+1
    tx = "Q{}".format(q)
    if q == 1:
        tx += "\n{}".format(mdates.num2date(x).year)
    return tx
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.FuncFormatter(func))
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=0, ha="center")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, if you look at the plots, rather than giving dates matplotlib is giving quarter values: [image: Plot for second example]

The dates in this case are exactly six months and therefore two quarters apart, which is presumably why you're seeing this behavior. While I can't find it in the docs, the numbers given by xlim in this case are consistent with being the number of quarters since the Unix Epoch (Jan. 1, 1970).

Comment: Thanks, I actually just noticed that after posting the question. This seems less than useful. In my case, it messed up lots of labels that depended on the original x limits. Still curious about whether this is intentional behavior or not, but I will accept your answer if nothing more exhaustive comes up.